# How do I identify support beams?

Tags: construction, remodeling

I'd like to remodel a couple rooms in our home, but am unsure how to identify support beams when the time comes. Are there any easily-identifiable things I should look for to keep my house from crashing to the ground?

Comment: Are you asking about how to determine whether a "Wall" is load bearing? Or are you asking for way to determine whether a horizontal beam in a wall is necessary?

Comment: Question about load bearing walls: http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/4/methods-to-determine-if-a-wall-is-load-bearing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If in doubt, don't. It might be worth paying a structural engineer to take a look and let you know if it's safe to remove a wall. Depending on the layout and age of the house, it may not be possible to know without doing some destruction down to the studs to see for sure.