# Is this a load-bearing wall between my house's entrance and dining room?

Tags: walls, load-bearing

I have recently bought a home in which there is a wall at right at the entrance of the foyer. Is there any way to tell if it is a load-bearing wall? I just want to get rid of it.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate [Are there ways to determine if a wall is load bearing?](http://diy.stackexchange.com/q/4/2196)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say it's almost certainly load bearing for one simple reason.

You've got what appears to be a beam running over the opening from the dining room to the hallway, and you don't have one going into the kitchen.

The fact that your dining/hall opening isn't floor to ceiling suggests strongly that the beam is running across that opening, which means it's running the depth of the house.

[image]

Comment: Hi @Greebo, In this situation what is the best way to remove this type of wall ?

Comment: @David That's a great question, and you should ask it as such. Better than trying to hash it out in a comment discussion here. Thanks.

Comment: Indeed.  I'm not going to try to answer that question in comments.

Comment: @ Greebo, I am writing another question for it. Thanks for answering this.

Comment: Added another question http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/37319/how-to-get-rid-of-a-load-bearing-wall