# Is this wall load bearing? See photos

Tags: walls, load-bearing, demolition

I'm looking to tear down the wall between my kitchen and dining room, and I'm wondering if it's load bearing.  If so, it's a 9' section that I want to remove.  Would two 2x10s with 1/2" plywood between them be sufficient, or would I need to go with either 2x12s or LVLs?  See the pictures below.  And if you need, I can take a picture of the floor joists from the basement.  This is the first floor of a two story colonial.

Thanks!
Chris
[image: celing]

[image: wall]

Comment: See many other similar questions. To hazard even a guess we would need to know which direction the floor joists go, and even then the right answer is to have an expert look at the actual building.  You also need expert advice to tell you how large an LVL header will be required, if it is load bearing.

Comment: See [tag:load-bearing] for similar questions. [This answer](http://diy.stackexchange.com/a/37301/157) in particular has some good tips.

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't trust a random individual on the internet to correctly identify bearing walls. There are general guidelines for identifying bearing walls, but many exceptions to the rules.

Get a competent person in your kitchen to look at the structure. From there, you can figure out the engineering.

Comment: As a random individual on the internet, I'd say that the substantial headers over the openings on each side would point to it being load bearing.