# How can I tell if this is a load bearing wall?

Tags: walls

[image]

Hello I would like to remove the wall from our family room to kitchen. The wall that I circled in yellow. How can I tell from this blueprint if it is a load bearing wall?

Comment: It's a 22' + wall @ the center of your structure. You should assume it is.

Comment: Which way are the floor joists going?

Comment: We would also need to see the second floor and see what it could be supporting.

Answer (score 3):

> I wouldn't trust a random individual on the internet to correctly identify bearing walls. There are general guidelines for identifying bearing walls, but many exceptions to the rules.
>
> Get a competent person in your house to look at the structure. From there, you can figure out the engineering.

*quote from https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/75057/2025*