# Removing a load bearing wall

Tags: walls, load-bearing

We're remodeling our bathroom and I would like to remove a wall that appears to be there for looks because of the style in the late 60s. I'm wondering if there is any possibility that this wall is a load bearing wall or if I'll have any issues when I remove it. It appears to be more of a decorative wall to me but I would like a second opinion. The wall runs perpendicular to the ceiling joists but there isn't anything bearing down on it when I go in the attic and the exterior wall which I know is load bearing is only about 5ft away. There are 3 or 4 ceiling joist that cross the wall and I plan to replace 1 (maybe more) of the ceiling joist because we found some termite damage when we pulled off the drywall. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I have attached 2 pictures of the wall I am referring to and I can go into the attic to take more picture if that would help to see what's up there.

[image: wall 1]

[image: wall 2]

EDIT:

Here are pictures of the attic above the wall. In the first image the wall I'd like to remove is just on the other side of the duct work. Second image is for a reference on how far away the duct work is from the wall. Third image is of the top of the wall (looking down onto it from the attic) with the insulation moved out of the way.

[![Wall location in attic][1]][1] [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcUBh.png

[![Wall distance from vent][2]][2]  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvi9h.png

[![Top of wall from attic][1]][1]  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMMmn.png

Comment: As with most of these (frequent) questions, we can't possibly say with certainty. I recommend this post: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/4/are-there-ways-to-determine-if-a-wall-is-load-bearing?rq=1

Comment: Don’t forget to get those termites taken care of

Comment: To answer your question in a comment below, we'd need to see your attic framing, the framing below this wall, and the footing situation. It's just not a practical question for the internet. Find someone local to give you a quick consultation and some peace of mind.

Comment: Hi isherwood. I'll go up in th3 attic tonight and take some pictures. The house is a single story on a slab so there's only concrete below the the wall. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Hi isherwood. I have edited my original post to include 3 images to show what is above the wall in the attic. And as I said before there is nothing but concrete below the wall since its on a slab and a single story. Please let me know what you think! Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure if this helps but I would also like to add that I have a hip roof and the wall in question does not run parallel to or under the the main ridge of the roof.

Answer (score 1):

The presence of the header and the double top plate suggests to me  that it might be load bearing. I would not remove the header or the jack studs on which it rests. The small decorative center post* in the living space can be removed. Presumably any partition below what we can see in the picture can be removed as long as the jack studs (and king studs) were not compromised.

**EDIT**

*By the small center post I mean the decorative post in the living space. I don't mean the small "cripple" in the space between the header and the top plate.

**EDIT**

Disclaimer: I am not really knowledgeable about framing.

Comment: I agree with Jim. +1 for commenting on the supports too.

Comment: No it doesn't. Many times I've installed such headers over wide openings to prevent sag. It looks like a 2x6 to me, which is what I'd use for that span, and which wouldn't carry roof load over such a span. It should also have standard stud spacing above it.

Comment: I reiterate that we can't know from what's shown.

Comment: Hi Jim. Thanks for your comment. Removing the small center post would remove any support the 2x6 header is supporting. Which is why I don't think it's holding any weight and can be removed. What do you think?

Comment: @TC 1989 I edited my answer to make clear that I was claiming that the decorative post BELOW the header could be removed. I do *not* think you should remove the short stud between the header and the top plate.  Presumably any partition below what we can see in the picture can be removed as long as the jack studs (and king studs) were not compromised.

Comment: With out being there and moving  insulation .That  does not at all look like a load bearing  wall .What is it holding up? joist span across .   The header  looks pretty missing  3/4 of its cripples  double plate would be sagging. and it is a single floor house . Main wall going down the center or a little off center is the load bearing wall ..Attic frame even looks like it has strong backs mid span.