# Remodeling 1950's home

Tags: fireplace, plaster, load-bearing

This is a single story home with a gable roof. I went in the attic and do not see a beam over the wall in question.  The wall in question is in between the kitchen and living room and there also is a fireplace on that wall.  I want to remove half of the wall, to the fireplace, to open the kitchen up.   There was a pocket door, hence the header mid way in the picture. Do you think it is load bearing from the construction behind the plaster?

[image: Interior of house]

Comment: Nobody can answer that without seeing the attic area above that wall.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, we'll need more info before we have any chance of helping you.

Comment: The direction of the trusses? With the limited info we don’t know much.

Comment: Before removing that much wall, you would need a structual engineer to approve.  I removed a short wall 10' between the kitch and dinning room, not "load bearing", and ran paralled to the joist, etc, etc..  But it was the only wall connecting the back wall of the house to an interior wall.  To remove the wall, required ceiling beams and foundation connecting the outter wall to the inter-wall.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are there ways to determine if a wall is load bearing?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/4/are-there-ways-to-determine-if-a-wall-is-load-bearing)

Answer (score 1):

- If the roof trusses run parallel as that wall it's *most likely* not load bearing.
- if the roof trusses run parallel to that wall and there is *not* a truss directly above the wall, it's *not* load bearing.
- If the trusses run perpendicular to that wall, then the wall *might* be load bearing.
- If the trusses run perpendicular to that wall and end directly above it or overlap slightly directly above that wall then it's *definitely* load bearing.

Based on the info you've provided, that's the best we can do.