# Is this closet door wall load bearing?

Tags: load-bearing

I want to remove the front wall of a closet that is directly entering the garage a d am wondering if this could be load bearing. There’s no wall or bean directly under in the basement, but there is a wall on the second floor.

Please help!

[image]

Comment: How do the joists run compared to that wall?  If joists run inline/same direction, then load bearing is less likely.  It would only hold one joist.

Comment: Or this? [Are there ways to determine if a wall is load bearing?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/4/are-there-ways-to-determine-if-a-wall-is-load-bearing)