# Can I remove double top plate?

Tags: walls, kitchens, interior, load

I am doing some renovation in my kitchen and when I removed the door that goes into kitchen, I came cross some sticking out wood from my ceiling and my wall and I am wondering if they can be removed at least partially.
Any help will be appreciated

[image]

Comment: Wait.  You didn't remove the door.  You removed two walls, one on either side of the door.  What's left is the top plate of a wall that had a door opening in it.  Why are you wondering ***now*** if you can remove what's left?  How do you know that wall wasn't structural?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP needs to hire a Structural Engineer yesterday.  We are not in a position to tell whether the structure is now dangerous.

Comment: Without the wall beneath it, the top plate is useless and can be removed. Was the wall useless, though? I see a header over a door in the background that suggests joists running parallel to your top plate. My expectation, then, is that this isn't a load bearing wall. Was there a similar header over the door that you removed? Technically there can exist brace walls running parallel to a ceiling joist, where I would peek in the attic to be sure that there's nothing strange going on up there. But in all likelihood you're okay completing the demolition.

Comment: One must wonder why the walls paralleling the one in question have double top plates, whereas the perpendicular ones only have single...

Comment: @popham, thanks for you response. It used to pantry on left and closet on right side which goes under the stairs.

Comment: Looks like the single top plates may have been nailed on top of (below) the ceiling sheet rock, whereas the double top plate was there before the ceiling sent up (normal wall construction).

Comment: Don't go closing this in a panic because "we need some engineerz!". Not really, and that doesn't help this person at all.

Comment: @Renas, but was there a big header over the old door? Like that header over the door in the background of your image?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit confusing. You've removed nearly the entirety of several walls, so why ask about the remaining boards now? At this point, here's my advice:

1. Read [Are there ways to determine if a wall is load bearing?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/4/are-there-ways-to-determine-if-a-wall-is-load-bearing) Find out whether you have a dangerous situation. If you do, get a post back in place pronto. If not...
2. Remove the top plates completely.
3. You may now have loose-fill insulation coming through the voids. You can remedy this any number of ways. One is to slide some cereal box board over the drywall (and any vapor barrier present) to bridge the gap while you repair the drywall.
4. Repair the vapor barrier, if necessary. I'd just slide a strip of poly sheeting into the channel, overlapping the existing as far as you can reasonably reach. No need to tape or caulk it if it's fit well.
5. Repair the drywall. You can float loose backing across the wall channel where you need it, screwing it to all pieces of drywall it contacts. Half inch plywood scrap works well.